# SQL Server data/input validation

Tags: sql-server, validation

I am considering adding validation on some insert and update statements for MS SQL Server 2005.
I want to be able to check the values inserted before it is written into the table - in this particular case, it is an integer field where the data must conform to a rule.
So a simple schema could be:

```
([id] [int] identity(1,1), [name] [nvarchar], [magicvalue] [int])
```

And magicvalue is the one I'm going to validate. However, it is a general question for the "best practice" when indexes and foreign key constraints are not suitable. I guess I am unsure whether triggers or constraints are the way to go, or if there are other ways.

An example is optional :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how complex the validation is. If you can do it in a constraint that is generally more efficient than a trigger. However, triigers can handle more complex validation which constraints cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Use constraints for this

e.g

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesHistory](
      [SaleID] [int]  NOT NULL,
      [Product] [char](150) NULL,
      [SaleDate] [datetime] NULL,
      [SalePrice] [money] NULL CHECK (SalePrice > 4)

)
```

Comment: That answer suited me fine for the purpose here, but I'm left wondering where then to use pre-commit triggers or rules (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258252(SQL.80).aspx). I know the latter is deprecated, but not what the replacement is.